# Running a python script in a windows service application (no user logged on)

Tags: c#, python, windows-services

Running a python script (developed in an other department) by a C# Windows Service application.

I wrote a console application which executes a python script. Now I tried to transform the console app into a Windows Service. The Windows Service is working without the script propper (loggin in event log). The service stopped at the point of starting ProcessStartInfo.

```cs
public string Run()
        {
            _pySkript.WorkingDirectory = _workinDirectory;
            _pySkript.FileName = _pythonPath;
            _pySkript.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}", a, b, c, d, e, f, g);
            _pySkript.UseShellExecute = false;
            _pySkript.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            _pySkript.CreateNoWindow = true;
            _pySkript.RedirectStandardError = true;
            _pySkript.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            _pySkript.ErrorDialog = false;
            _pySkript.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            using (Process process = Process.Start(_pySkript))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    OnScriptRunFinished();
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: The service stopped at the start of ProcessStartInfo. At the point where the script is started.

Comment: thats not the error, if its not starting there will be an error.. you need to trap for it and write/display it somewhere then you will work out why its not working

Comment: The service is stopped by the Service App in Windows. It interrupts at Process.Start with the error message like this: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3wmV.png)

Comment: Cant view that.. work restrictions block that site - if you read the SO rules, it also says dont use links.  Post the error message returned from the process.start, or, google what it means

Comment: Error Message: Service bla was started on Local Computer and then dialed. Some services are automatically stopped if they are not used by other services or programs

Comment: But thats not the error returned from the process.start.. trap it, write it to a file somewhere..

Comment: The Console App is using the exact same class and settings and it works. The Service App reports this error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system can not find the specified file at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (ProcessStartInfo startInfo ) at Ui.SapToolkitConnectorServiceApp.SapToolkitConnectorService.test () in D: \ GitRepos \ saptoolkitconnector \ Ui \ Ui.SapToolkitConnectorServiceApp \ SapToolkitConnectorService.cs: line 206.

Comment: So..... the path it has isnt available....... where is the script and what user do you have the script running as?

Comment: But a console app runs as you, a service account even running as you does not get the exact same environment..

Comment: @BugFinder I have in one solution a console application an the service both use the same code to run the script. The console application is working as expected. If I install the service app the script is not working. The hole config ProcessStarInfo is the same. What means in your answer that these application are not in the same enviroment? Is the service not able to start the script even if the GUI of the hidden? Thanks

Comment: When a service is run, even if it runs as your account it doesnt run scripts, so various drives, etc are not necessarily available, you havent answered if it runs the service as you, or any other account, if its another account it possibly doesnt have the same rights.. There is just not enough information here. I suggest you read up on services and limitations

Comment: @BugFinder I run the service with the same user. But in a different way you are right :-) There was a spelling mistake. I wrote an example. This works finde. Thanks a lot for your Help. I will post my example code mybe some has the same problem/any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @BugFinder for his support. At the end it was a spelling mistake.

Example solution:

First project: Logic.csproj

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Logic
{
public class RunScript
{
    string _parameterString = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}","main.py", "Testuser", "TestPw", "MyEnviroment");
    string _resultCon;
    public string Start()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo _pySkript = new ProcessStartInfo();

        _pySkript.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\GitRepos\ScriptRunner\PyScript\";
        _pySkript.FileName = "python";
        _pySkript.Arguments = _parameterString;
        _pySkript.UseShellExecute = false;
        _pySkript.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        _pySkript.CreateNoWindow = true;
        _pySkript.RedirectStandardError = true;
        _pySkript.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        _pySkript.ErrorDialog = false;
        _pySkript.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        try
        {
            using (Process process = Process.Start(_pySkript))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    _resultCon = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _resultCon = ex.ToString();
        }
        return _resultCon;
    }
  }
}
```

Second project: ScriptRunner.csproj

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Logic;

namespace ScriptRunner
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var runMyScript = new RunScript();
        Console.WriteLine(runMyScript.Start());
    }
  }
}
```

Third project: ScriptRunnerService.csproj

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using Logic;

namespace ScriptRunnerService
{
public partial class ScriptRunService : ServiceBase
{
    public ScriptRunService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        eventLog1 = new EventLog();
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "MySource", "MyNewLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
        eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";

        var runMyScript = new RunScript();
        var output = runMyScript.Start();
        eventLog1.WriteEntry(output.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStop.", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
  }
}
```

**Install Service:**

*You need InstallUtil.exe to install the service!*

installutil -i  ScriptRunnerService.exe

Windows-Key: r
services.msc -> Start Service
eventvwr.msc -> Check Logs

**Uninstall Service:**

installutil -u ScriptRunnerService.exe

***Finde complete solution incl. python script on [GitHub](https://github.com/0x53olution/RunPythonScriptByService)***